# MySQL query taking a long time. I've tried many variations of the query, and nothing seems to affect the speed

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Here is my query as it stands and the structure data:

```
   SELECT * 
     FROM gmm_sql as a
LEFT JOIN usds as b ON a.dp_id = b.dp_id
LEFT JOIN usdsown as c ON b.dp_id = c.dp_id 
    WHERE a.comm like '%tree%'
```

- **gmm_sql:** 21 fields. All fields varchar() mixed from 20 - 255. **4,882 records.**
- **usds:** 7 fields. All fields varchar() mixed from 20 - 255. **304,713 records.**
- **usdsown:** 14 fields. All fields varchar() mixed from 20 - 255. **107,606 records.**

I've confirmed there are matches manually. I am using MySQL Workbench to run these query tests. The query just keeps running for 10 mins and does not stop...

Am I doing something seriously wrong?

Here is an EXPLAIN output:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra 
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3973    Using where
1   SIMPLE  b   ALL dp_id   NULL    NULL    NULL    304345  
1   SIMPLE  c   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    105711
```

Comment: If the fields are all var_chars, that's probably not good design. Have you created any indexes?

Comment: Please attach to your question an output of `EXPLAIN` for ths query: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: I'd start by looking at the EXPLAIN output. Those joins will be very expensive if there aren't indexes on those dp_id columns

Comment: also '%' at the beginning of a 'like' takes a lot longer than after. If you reversed the content (e.g. 'eert') of the field you could you use ...a.com like 'eert%'

Comment: I added the EXPLAIN output above.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments. I changed the id field to numeric and added indexes to each one. The query runs blazing now!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the id fields are indexed, this is still potentially a huge data set.  Then you have a final where clause on a varchar with wildcards... this will cause a full table scan of your entire result set and negate any index on the a.comm field.

Just curious, but can you test it by changing the select * to a 'select count(a.comm)' and drop the where clause.  If it still takes forever it's the where clause, otherwise it's the building of the result set.

Answer (score 2):

Make **FULLTEXT** index on gmm_sql.gmm. + Make sure you have all the foreign keys indexed.

`WHERE a.comm like '%tree%'` is the most costly operation on your data. You have literaly to do **full table scan.** Normal index do not suffice, because you have **wildcard at the begining** of the match sequence.

Alternatively, you can use **lucene** or **sphynx** if your database does not support this type of index.

Answer (score 2):

The first point of contention I see is:

```
WHERE a.comm like '%tree%'
```

Even if you have an index on `GMM_SQL.comm`, wildcarding the left side of the string renders the index useless.  While this works, it is literally the worst performing way to search content whose data type is string related.

Full Text Search ([MySQL specific link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)) is the preferred method of finding content within a string.  But IIRC, MySQL still requires the table to be MyISAM...

The next point is:

```
SELECT *
```

This is returning *all* columns from *all* the tables that are JOIN'd.  The SELECT clause should only contain the columns that are actually necessary, because:

1. You're returning more data than you need to
2. The data type can really screw with performance - IE: if one of the columns is a very long string, or binary/BLOB data

Third - your JOIN criteria.  The smaller the data type, the faster the query.  I'm going to assume anything with `id` implies `INT`.  Don't use `BIGINT` if you don't need it.